# RTSP error - Segmenation fault

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I get "segmentation fault" error when I play the following RTSP plugin:

```
./TEST "( v4l2src always-copy=FALSE input-src=composite ! video/x-raw-yuv,format=\(fourcc\)NV12, width=320,height=240 ! queue ! dmaiaccel ! dmaienc_h264 encodingpreset=2 ratecontrol=2 intraframeinterval=23 idrinterval=46 targetbitrate=1000000 ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )"
```

TEST is the test-launch application from rtsp examples. I get the following error:

```
davinci_resizer davinci_resizer.2: RSZ_G_CONFIG:0:1:124
vpfe-capture vpfe-capture: IPIPE Chained
vpfe-capture vpfe-capture: Resizer present
tvp514x 1-005d: tvp5146 (Version - 0x03) found at 0xba (DaVinci I2C adapter)
vpfe-capture vpfe-capture: dma_alloc_coherent size 7168000 failed
Segmentation fault
```

Can anyone tell me as to what is going wrong.

Thanks,
Maz

Answer (score 0):

See vpfe-capture vpfe-capture: dma_alloc_coherent size 7168000 failed

memory allocation has failed somewhere in your capture driver. This question is better suited for TI's e2e list, no? I don't think this ia a gstreamer generic issue but issue specific to the embedded hardware.

Why don't you get a simple filesrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay  pipeline up first and then slowly make it more and more complicated. [replace bitstream with yuv and do encoding, then add the capture]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tired using "videotestsrc ! video/x-raw-yuv,format=\(fourcc\)NV12, width=640,height=480 ! queue ! dmaiaccel ! dmaienc_h264 ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96" it works fine. But when I replace it with the above pipeline it fails.

Comment: Well you will have to best get this answered on ti e2e. This seems like some memory allocation problem with capture. Perhaps contigous memory not getting assigned or something like that. You know it is the capture that is the issue because the other pipeline is working.